# Difference between Class Inherit, extend and implement oops

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I know this is a stupid question, but still want to know it clearly.
The proper difference between
**Inheriting a class**,
**extending a class**,
**Implementing a class**

Please explain with examples.

And if you can provide me a source for a complete detailed oops in c# for studying.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is literally no difference. This is just various nomenclature used to discuss the topic of inheritance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To clarify what Feisty Mango commented:

`Inheriting` refers to the relationship between a derived class (the child) and the base class (the parent). The derived class can use certain methods and fields within the base class according to [accessibility levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels).

`Extending` is interchangeable with `Inheriting` and usually is used in java (since the syntax for inheritance in java is the keyword `extends`. In C#, it is colon `:`

`Implementing` usually is used with interfaces instead of classes. Mainly because `inheriting` or `extending` implies parts of classes are being consumed, where with `implementing`, it implies the entire interface must be defined by whoever implements it.

Another thing to keep in mind is that you can only `extend` or `inherit` one class in C#, but can implement multiple interfaces!

Microsoft Docs provides good information related to [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance) (here, among other places).

Comment: Mind that C# has "extension methods", which are not part of a given class, but count as "extending" it. That would imply a fundamental difference between "inheriting/subclassing" and "extending (in the sense of extension methods)".