# Create custom iterable Dictionary with one generic type

Tags: c#

I would like to create a "List" of items which contains unique `Type` keys, keyed by the type of the item itself. I created a collection that holds a `Dictionary<Type, V>` and manages it.

```
internal class TypeCollection<V>
{
    public TypeCollection()
    {
        items = new Dictionary<Type, V>();
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, V> items;

    public void Add<T>(T value) where T : V
    {
        items.Add(typeof(T), value);
    }

    public void Remove(Type type)
    {
        items.Remove(type);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value) where T : V
    {
        if (items.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out V foundValue))
        {
            value = (T)foundValue;
            return true;
        }

        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have to iterate through the values. A `for-loop` is not possible, because I have to access a value by its type but a `foreach-loop` can do the job. I implemented the `IEnumerable` interface

```
TypeCollection<V> : IEnumerable<V>
```

and added the required interface methods

```
    public IEnumerator<V> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (V value in items.Values)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

When I want to remove all the values from that collection I would have to implement this

```
    public void Clear()
    {
        items.Clear();
    }
```

As you might have noticed I was going to reinvent a Dictionary and why should I do that...

I created this

```
internal class TypeCollection<V> : Dictionary<Type, V>
{
    public void Add<T>(T value) where T : V
    {
        Add(typeof(T), value);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value) where T : V
    {
        if (TryGetValue(typeof(T), out V foundValue))
        {
            value = (T)foundValue;
            return true;
        }

        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

but I am not able to override the default `Add` and `TryGetValue` method. I would always have both methods, `Add` and `Add<>` so what is the "cleanest" way? I would like to hide the default `Add` and `TryGetValue` methods because there is no need to use them anymore.

Comment: Have you looked at the system type [`System.Collections.Generic.KeyedByTypeCollection<TItem>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: How about simply `public class TypeCollection<V> : Dictionary<Type, V> { }` ?

Comment: The `KeyedByTypeCollection` is exactly what you need. You could also use a `HashSet` with a custom `IEqualityComparer` that compares the objects type

Comment: See: [Uses of KeyedByTypeCollection in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330387).

Comment: @dbc if you want you can create an answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than creating your own custom `TypeCollection<TValue>`, you can use the existing [`KeyedByTypeCollection<TItem>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) in `System.Collections.Generic`:

> **`KeyedByTypeCollection<TItem> Class`**
>
> Provides a collection whose items are types that serve as keys.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> Only one object of each type is allowed in the collection because the type is the key and each key must be unique. But you can find objects of different types.

However, you may need to subclass it and extend it to include a convenient `TryGetValue<T>(out T value)` like so:

```
public class TypeCollection<V> : KeyedByTypeCollection<V>
{
    public T ValueOrDefault<T>() where T : V
    {
        if (!Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        return (T)this[typeof(T)];
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value) where T : V
    {
        if (!Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        value = (T)this[typeof(T)];
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is because the [`KeyedByTypeCollection<V>.Find<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_KeyedByTypeCollection_1_Find__1) method returns *the first item in the collection of the specified type `T`*, so in cases where you have a complex polymorphic type hierarchy it may return an instance of a derived type when a base type is present:

```
var dictionary = new KeyedByTypeCollection<object>();

dictionary.Add("hello");
dictionary.Add(new object());

Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.Find<object>().GetType() == typeof(object)); // FAILS
```

For further examples of use, see *[Uses of KeyedByTypeCollection in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330387/3744182)*.

Comment: does it have a `TryGetValue` method? I think I would have to extend it

Comment: well I don't know if this is really the thing I am looking for because find does the following `Returns the first item in the collection of a specified type.` but this collection should only have one item per type?

Comment: @MHComputech - sorry about that, been a while since I used this type.  Answer updated.

Comment: Do you think the `Contains` check is as fast as my custom `TryGetValue` method? Maybe faster? Or less?

Comment: and should I extend it or inherit from it ... ?

Comment: @MHComputech - 1) performance: no way to know without testing.  The underlying lookup should be via a hash table either way.  2) *extend it or inherit from it* -- we may be using inconsistent terminology, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22573918) says they mean the same thing.  But i don't think an extension method would be convenient -- I couldn't find a way to get automatic type inferencing to work conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

You can reintroduce these methods and make them private:

```
    private new void Add(Type key, V value)
    {

    }

    private new bool TryGetValue(Type key, out V value)
    {
        value = default(V);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem there are two ways: inheritance and composition.
Inheritance does not allow you to exclude base class methods, so `Dictionary` is not the best base class for your type.

In composition there is no such problem, because you deside what methods to expose. And this is normal way.

Solution: use composition or find new better base class.

Comment: So you would prefer my first solution instead of the second?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `IDictionary` interface instead:

```
internal class TypeCollection<V> : IDictionary<Type, V>
{
    protected readonly Dictionary _innerDictionary = new Dictionary<Type,V>();

}
```

Once you type that much, Visual Studio will underline parts of the code and show an error reminding you that you haven't implemented the interface yet. Right click the error and choose "implement interface through _innerDictionary" and it'll autogenerate everything you need to wire up the methods to `_innerDictionary`. Then you can modify whatever you want.